# Existence of a special homeomorphism on $\mathbb{T}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Let $A, B$ be closed topological subspaces of $\mathbb{T}^2$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces.

> **My Question:** Is it possible to construct a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{T}^2 \to
>  \mathbb{T}^2$, such that $h(A) = B?$

If necessary, we can assume $A$ and $B$ as $\mathcal{C}^0$- manifold with boundary (topological manifold with boundary).

I've been stuck in this problem for a long time; everything I tried did not come close to achieving the result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is impossible in general, when $A, B$ are topological circles. When each of them is a disjoint union of compact arcs, such a homeomorphism does exist, but  it is not completely trivial. One needs Schoenflies theorem for topological arcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's not possible. Consider A = circle that you can colapse in a point and B = circle that "cuts" the torus(One generator of the fundamental group). So $A^c$ retracts to a 8 shapped figure and $B^c$ is a cilinder.

Comment: Perfect counter-exemple.